# funcionamiento de while con "and" y "or"

Tags: python-3.7

Porque el bucle while no funciona bien con el operador "and" para validar varias variables y funciona solo con "or"?
Intente usar varias variables para validar la salida del bucle, pero con tal que una sola variable es este bien ya me aceptaba salir del bucle.

Aquí indico el código como lo escribí el cual me funcionó de esa forma

```
**print("Programa de becas")
escuela= input("Nombre de la escuela: ")
año= input("Año de estudio: ")
edad= int(input("edad: "))
while escuela!="JUAN" or año!= "QUINTO" or edad!=15:
    print("ingrese los datos de nuevo")

    escuela= input("Nombre de la escuela: ")
    año= input("Año de estudio: ")
    edad= int(input("edad: "))

print("FELICIDADES")
print("REQUISITOS ACEPTADOS, SIGA CON LOS SIGUIENTES")**
```

Answer (score 1):

He probado el código eliminando los asteriscos del primer y útimo print y sustituyendo el operador or por el operador lógico and y no ha lanzado ningún error

```
print("Programa de becas")
escuela = input("Nombre de la escuela: ")
año = input("Año de estudio: ")
edad = int(input("edad: "))

while escuela != "JUAN" and año != "QUINTO" and edad != 15:
    print("ingrese los datos de nuevo")

    escuela = input("Nombre de la escuela: ")
    año = input("Año de estudio: ")
    edad = int(input("edad: "))

print("FELICIDADES")
print("REQUISITOS ACEPTADOS, SIGA CON LOS SIGUIENTES")
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisa un poco los conceptos de lógica booleana en programación. Los lenguajes de programación están diseñados para ser eficientes, por ende NO hacen más cosas de las que deberían. Si tienes comparaciones condicionales múltiples, apenas se cumple una situación de salida, se termina la comparación.

una comparación con `and` es verdadera únicamente si TODAS las condicionales son verdaderas, apenas encuentre una condición falsa, se terminará la comparación

```
>>> True and 3>7 and 1/0
False
```

`True` de por si es verdadero, pero seguidamente encuentra un `3>7` que es `False`, lo que termina inmediatamente la comparación dejando la **división por cero** sin evaluar.

Ahora este otro caso:

```
>>> True and 7>3 and 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Las dos primeras condiciones son verdaderas, lo que obliga al intérprete a evaluar la siguiente condición (1/0) y saltará el error.

Con `or`, solo basta que una condición sea verdadera para dar por finalizada la comparación.

```
>>> True or 1/0 or 1/0
True
>>> False or 7>3 or 1/0 # La condicion verdadera es 7>3
True
>>> False or 3>7 or 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Teniendo claro ese concepto, entonces para que solo salga del ciclo si se cumplen TODAS las condiciones, entonces tiene que ser:

```
print("Programa de becas")

while True:
    escuela = input("Nombre de la escuela: ")
    año = input("Año de estudio: ")
    edad = int(input("edad: "))
    if escuela == "JUAN" and año == "QUINTO" and edad == 15:
        break # Esto termina el while
    print("Ingrese los datos de nuevo")

print("FELICIDADES")
print("REQUISITOS ACEPTADOS, SIGA CON LOS SIGUIENTES")
```

Comment: en la parte if escuela == *codigo*.... si no se cumple la condicion hace el print() pero no seria mejor poner un else: print()?

Comment: @hhjjdd da lo mismo. La única forma de que se imprima "ingrese los datos de nuevo" es que no se cumpla el `if`, y viceversa, como si estuviera simulando un `else`. Es una forma un poco más "vistosa" de hacerlo, pero si se colocara un `else`, funciona igual.